# How to go bot online on Python

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm having some difficulties getting the bot online. When I run the file the bot is not online on the server I need. Before I used pycharm but due to many errors on my computer, I migrated to VSCode. In pycharm it worked normally, but now in VSCode I can't make it work. Can someone help me?

The variables **token** and **canal_id** are correcty configured on my code and i already check on **My applications** on discord.

Code:

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

token = 'TOKEN' 
canal_id = 0000
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='%') 

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Got online')

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: Please share what specific errors you are having. Also are you sure you have discord.py installed in VScode?

Comment: You should get an error atleast. It's not easy to help if we don't know what error you're getting, this leaves us guessing and this can't be so easy. To debug or run in VSCode it's the F5 key. well if discord.py is installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```